# selenium webriverwait raises error without description

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

this:

```py
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username')))
```

gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spammer.py", line 100, in <module>
    bot()
  File "spammer.py", line 75, in bot
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'inputSession')))
  File "C:\Users\matthijs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

and now my question is not only about how to fix this issue but also why is there no message about what is making this error happening. any ideas?

Comment: Can you update what Selenium version are you using?

Comment: i use selenium version 3.141.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an error message because how `element_to_be_clickable` and `until` are built

[expected_conditions](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py)

`element_to_be_clickable` calls `visibility_of_element_located` which in turn calls `_find_element`. This is the only function that might throw unhandled exception in this flow

```
def _find_element(driver, by):
    try:
        return driver.find_element(*by)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        raise e
    except WebDriverException as e:
        raise e
```

As you can see in [selenium.common.exceptions](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.common.exceptions), all the exceptions have `stacktrace=None` as default

```
exception selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException(msg=None, screen=None, stacktrace=None)
```

So although [until](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py) tries to get the stacktrace before raising the exception

```
# partial function
def until(self, method, message=''):
    stacktrace = None

    while True:
        try:
            value = method(self._driver) # calls element_to_be_clickable.__call__ 
        except self._ignored_exceptions as exc: # NoSuchElementException
            stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

The stacktrace is still `None`, so there is nothing to print.